# Set size of text to a portion of viewport

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This question is regarding very basic CSS functionality but i am a noob so bear with me,

In css when setting the dimensions of an element you can use the viewport format (vh/vw) to make the element fill up portion of the page:

```
div {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

This does not seem to work for text.
When using the styling above for an element that contains text the size of the text itself seem to be unaffected.

The result I need to achieve is to keep the size of a text static, even when zooming in / out in the page. For divs and such it can be achieved by using the viewport format but the text inside the div is unaffected.

How can you set the size of a text to be static in CSS, even when the page is zoomed in / out?

Comment: You can set the font-size to for example 10vw. like this `<span style="font-size: 10vw">MyText</span>`. Does that help?

Comment: It did not work unfortunately @xDrago

Comment: You will need to explain exactly what you mean with zoomed in / out as @xDrago works as suggested when using [Ctrl+] or [Ctrl-] or [Ctrl-Mousewheel] (zooming the browser window in/out, just tested it in Chrome/Edge/Firefox and IE11).

Comment: @RenevanderLende I am not sure what you mean exactly. His answer did not work perfectly perhaps but when tweaking both height and font-size i got a good result. I think that should be the accepted answer because it provided the correct properties to use.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right. I mistook my own browser resize for a zoom in/out. I'll remove the remark... Been doing too many things at the same time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet.

```css
#header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 10vh;
    line-height: 10vh;
    font-size: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id = "header">This is a line of text</div>
```

Comment: codepen https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/bGpLxKb

Comment: Thanks! It worked! By the way, it seems line-height was not needed, at least not in my case. What was the purpose of line-height here?

Comment: a lazy way to center the text vertically in the div haha. It's not mandatory indeed & I would probably use something like flexbox in production. Glad I could help.